# .net framework- how to create IServiceProvider to get already registered service instance using IServiceProvider?

Tags: dependency-injection, windows-services, .net-framework-version, light-inject

On **.NET Framework 4.6.2** application, where there is no built-in DI container we are using **LightInject** DI Container to object initialization but don't know how to create 'IServiceProvider' Object in Main() so the other class implementations can get the already registered instance of service via `IServiceProvider` without using `new` keyword.

How to create `IServiceProvider` object? in .net framework 4.6.2 application

```
public class Program
{       
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new ServiceContainer();

        // calls below extension method
        container.RegisterDependencies();
    }
}

public static class LightInjectDIExtension
{        
    /// Registers the application dependencies.        
    public static void RegisterDependencies(this ServiceContainer container)
    {
        container.Register<IBackgroundService1, BackgroundService1>();
        container.Register<Service2>();
    }
}
```

Once `IServiceProvider` instance is available to use, I'm intended to do the below

```
// This is background service app & this class will be 
// instantiated once in application lifetime 
public class BackgroundService1 : IBackgroundService1
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public BackgroundService1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void Method1(string elementName)
    {
        // every time call to 'Method1' has to get the new instance
        // of registered 'Service2' class rather than using 'new'
        // keyword
        var service2 =  (Service2)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Service2)); 
        service2.CallMe();
    }
 }
```

Modification after Steven's suggestion

```
 public class BackgroundService1 : IBackgroundService1
{
    private readonly IServiceContainer_container;
    public BackgroundService1 (IServiceContainer container)
  //Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in LightInject.dll
    {
       _container = container;
    }

    public void Method1(string elementName)
    {
        // every time call to 'Method1' has to get the new instance
        // of registered 'Service2' class rather than using 'new'
        // keyword
        var service2 =  (Service2)_container.GetInstance(typeof(Service2)); 
        service2.CallMe();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, injecting an `IServiceProvider` (or any abstraction that gives access to an unbound set of dependencies is a bad idea, because it can lead to the Service Locator anti-pattern. A discussion on this anti-pattern can be found [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

A Service Locator is something that only exists *outside* the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Your `BackgroundService1`, however, might be part of the Composition Root, which might injecting a DI Container -or an abstraction there over- a feasible solution. Note that you should strive keeping all business logic out of the Composition Root. This ensures that `BackgroundService1` purely functions as a mechanical peace of code that delegates the operation to classes that run the actual business logic.

Though, when operating inside the Composition Root, there is typically no need to use an abstraction over your DI Container, such as an `IServiceProvider`. The Composition Root already has intrinsic knowledge over all application's dependencies, including your DI Container.

This means that you can inject LightInject's `ServiceContainer` directly into the constructor of `BackgroundService1`; there is no need for an `IServiceProvider`.

If, however, you insist in using the `IServiceProvider` abstraction, you can create an `IServiceProvider` implementation that wraps `ServiceContainer` and forwards its `GetService` method to the wrapped `ServiceContainer`. This wrapper class can than be registered in the `ServiceContainer`.

Comment: @ Steven, in short you are proposing to inject 'ServiceContainer' (rather than IServiceProvider) into the constructor of BackgroundService1 because injecting IServiceProvider is antipattern. Am I right? With that understanding I have updated post with recent changes & its related error

Comment: @ecma-402: no, that's not what I'm saying. From perspective of the anti-pattern, there is no difference between injecting `ServiceContainer` or `IServiceProvider`. Both injections are the same anti-pattern when `BackgroundService1` lives outside the Composition Root, and both injections are fine (not implementation of the anti-pattern) when `BackgroundService1` is part of the Composition Root.

Comment: Note that it might be that LightInject does not allow resolving the `ServiceContainer` as service from itself. If that's the case, you should add an `container.RegisterInstance<IServiceContainer>(container)` call to your DI configuration.

Comment: @ Steven, how to identify the BackgroundService1 is part of the Composition Root or not? question may be basic but I don't know the answer at the moment.

Comment: Whether something is part of the Composition Root is an architectural decision, which means it is up to you. But it basically means the class is located close to the application startup path (your `Program.Main` method); and ideally in the same assembly.

Comment: @ Steven, from your above comment I can confirm my BackgroundService1 (class naming may be incorrect) is one of the classes in the same assembly where other classes/modules lives.  Moreover, in my implementation, object graph is like main() calls 'class1' where class1 depends class2 and class2 depends on BackgroundService1, hope this confirm BackgroundService1 is part of Composition root therefore using container.RegisterInstance<IServiceContainer>(container) in DI config to inject 'ServiceContainer' in consuming class is not an antipattern. Am I correct?

Comment: @ecma-402: that sure sounds valid.